# javascript non multi-touch events

Tags: javascript

I am developing a small embedded application which uses a resistive touch screen (ADS 7846) that does not support multi-touch gestures.

The problem is that when using a finger (or other object) to touch the screen, the mousedown event only gets fired when the finger is released, if fact both the mousedown and mouseup events get fired only when the finger is removed.

```
function $(id) {return document.getElementById(id)};

$("butsetup").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  alert('down');
});

$("butsetup").addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  alert('up');
});
```

Is there a solution to make this work as expected ?

As suggested by @antyrat this reports true:

```
alert( 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement )
```

But I read somewhere that some browsers 'expose' this capability to the dom but do not enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `touchstart` and `touchend` events:

```
$("butsetup").addEventListener( ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? "touchstart" : "mousedown", function(e) {
  alert('down');
});

$("butsetup").addEventListener( ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? "touchend" : "mouseout", function(e) {
  alert('up');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that touchstart and touchend do not fire at all !

Comment: can you try run in console "'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement"? And look what it return?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there is no javascript console, I am using midori on a 320 x 240 screen!

Comment: so try then use this: `alert( 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement )`

Comment: Yes, that reported true !

Comment: So problems seems to be in other place. Touch events should work. Try to use debugger. And what framework are you using? As I see you have `$` sign. If you use jQuery `$("butsetup").on` should be instaed of `addEventListener`. Also `butsetup` not seem like correct selector, if it's class name should be `.butsetup`

Answer (score 0):

Use `touchstart` and `touchend` events .

```
$("butsetup").addEventListener("touchstart", function(event){  
    alert('touchstart');
}, true);

$("butsetup").addEventListener("touchend", function(event){  
    alert('touchend');
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the touchstart and touchend events do not fire.

Comment: I think is something wrong with the element or the jquery. does touchstart return any objects or is null? These events tested and works fine!

Comment: oops sorrie, I am not using jquery, $() is an alias to document.getElementById()

Comment: oouf :) this happens!